# How to input a comment on csh?

Tags: comments, csh

In `bash`, I used `#` to input comment. Even on interactive session.

```
bash-3.2$ #
bash-3.2$ #
bash-3.2$ #
bash-3.2$
```

`csh` spits error for this. How can I input some comment on interactive `csh` session? In other words, I am looking for a way to make 100% sure comment in `csh`.

```
root@freebsd9:~ # #
#: Command not found.
root@freebsd9:~ # # 3e
#: Command not found.
root@freebsd9:~ # #
#: Command not found.
root@freebsd9:~ #
```

Comment: just for fun in interactive csh you can delete all files ending with a hash with `rm *#`. Put that in a script and something different happens.

Comment: @george If it's true, it's really awful! And I don't want to prove it myself!

Comment: oh yes, something I learned the hard way many years ago creating a script to clean up emacs autosave files.. bash seems to need a space in front of the # to indicate a comment by the way.

Comment: @george: A `#` comment can be at the beginning of a line. Otherwise, you need whitespace separating it from the preceding token. `echo foo#bar` prints "foo#bar"; `echo foo #bar` prints "foo".

Comment: Please read my updated answer. I was mistaken about how `:` works in csh (as opposed to tcsh).

Comment: In bash and zsh, the behavior is configurable; see the option variously spelled `interactive_comments`, `interactive-comments`, or `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interactive csh or tcsh doesn't do comments. The `#` character introduces a comment only in a script. (This is unlike the behavior of sh and its derivatives. In bash and zsh, the behavior is configurable.) Quoting the `csh` man page (from Solaris 9, one of the remaining systems where `csh` is not just a symlink to `tcsh`):

> When the shell's input is not a terminal, the character #
> introduces  a comment that continues to the end of the input  line.
> Its special meaning is suppressed when preceded by a \  or enclosed in
> matching quotes.

The point, I think, is that interactive commands don't need comments.

**If you're using tcsh**, you can do something similar with the built-in `:` command, which does nothing:

```
% : 'This is not a comment, but it acts like one.'
```

(where `%` represents the shell prompt and `:` is the command).  Quoting the argument is a good idea; otherwise, though the command is not executed, it can have some effect:

```
% : This will create the file "oops.txt" > oops.txt
```

Note that since `:` is a command, it must be followed by a space.

The `:` command was originally introduced in a very early version of the Bourne shell, or perhaps even before that.

However, the `/bin/csh` version of the `:` command does not permit any arguments, making it useless as a comment replacement:

```
csh% : 'This will not work.'
:: Too many arguments
csh%
```

(I didn't realize that when I initially posted this answer. I must have tested it with tcsh rather than a true csh.)

Since `:` doesn't work in pure csh, the next best solution is probably to use `echo` and redirect the output:

```
csh% echo 'This is not a comment, but it acts like one.' > /dev/null
```

Obligatory link: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: I think now I understand why people stop using `csh`. And just for note, I wanted this for copy & paste a lot of code just as a quick REPL.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Not sure why this and an unrelated answer of mine were downvoted 12 seconds apart. Coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

For the reference, I like to note my current workaround. It's using `echo`.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
echo "This is comment line."
echo "But still, beware... Because `expression` is still being evaluated.
```

This is the best way I could find.

Comment: If it's in a script, as implied by the `#!/bin/tcsh` line, you can just use normal `#` comments.

Answer (score 2):

To use # for interactive comments in tcsh or csh, this seems to work in most cases:

```
alias '#' 'echo \!* >> /dev/null'
```

It can be run by the user interactively or placed in a *.tcshrc* or *.cshrc* configuration file as appropriate.

*(The alias can obviously be named differently as you might desire; normal restrictions apply.)*

---

Note: as Keith Thompson noted above, this will still give errors if your comment includes redirect characters such as `>` or `>>`, but used this way does not appear to actually create an undesired redirect file. Surrounding the comment in single quotes (`'`) is still a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! You rock. The best answer here, I hope it will get noticed.

Answer (score -2):

Check if your script has UNIX EOL Format. Has some problem with Windows EOL Format.